# Rake DB Migrate MySQL

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails, rake

Can someone help me out? Setting up a local Rails 2.2.2 project but rake is failing. The mysql gem was installed:

Installed MySQL gem like so:

```
sudo gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-config=/usr/local/mysql/bin/mysql_config
Successfully installed mysql-2.9.0
1 gem installed
Installing ri documentation for mysql-2.9.0...
Installing RDoc documentation for mysql-2.9.0...
```

Then tried to call rake:

```
$ rake --trace db:migrate
```

** Invoke db:migrate (first_time)
** Invoke environment (first_time)
** Execute environment
** Execute db:migrate
!!! The bundled mysql.rb driver has been removed from Rails 2.2. 

Please install the mysql gem and try again: gem install mysql.

rake aborted!
dlopen(/Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.9.0/lib/mysql/mysql_api.bundle, 9): Library not loaded: libmysqlclient.18.dylib
  Referenced from: /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.9.0/lib/mysql/mysql_api.bundle
  Reason: image not found - /Library/Ruby/Gems/1.8/gems/mysql-2.9.0/lib/mysql/mysql_api.bundle

Comment: I forget if Rails 2 used a Gemfile, but if it does, you would need to specify that the app should use the gem there.  Sorry, it's been years since I used 2.x, but there's some place in the app that you need to declare that it should use the gem you installed to connect and operate with MySQL.

Comment: Thanks. Adding the dynamic library path to the .profile and .bash_profile fixed it.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Adding the mysql lib path to `.bash_profile` and `.profile` fixed it:

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Answer (score 1):

On Mavericks with rvm ruby1.8.7 and rails 2.3 I had to install mysql gem with

```
gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-dir=/usr/local/mysql
```

and then I needed export from Slinky's answer added to my .zshenv

```
export DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH=/usr/local/mysql/lib:$DYLD_LIBRARY_PATH
```

Answer (score 0):

Issue - !!! The bundled mysql.rb driver has been removed from Rails 2.2. Please install
the mysql gem and try again: gem install mysql.
rake aborted!
no such file to load -- mysql/mysql_api

Steps to Resolution -

1) gem install mysql -- --with-mysql-dir= Path_to_MySQL_root_folder

2) Running this command will show a link for download like this-
http://dev.mysql.com/get/Downloads/Connector-C/mysql-connector-c-noinstall-6.0.2-win32.zip/from/pick

3) Copy lib/libmysql from this download folder to C:/Ruby/bin